# data provider with dependsonmethod not excuting as expected

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng

I am trying to run Test script for Login and logout. Login and logout both are methods. I have used data provider with login method for data driven framework and logout method is depends on login. But when i execute, login methods with its all data and logout executes at the end only once. How I can execute login-logout one after other for data driven frame work.Thanks for any help.

```
 @Test(dataProvider = "DP")
       public void login(String Usrname, String Pwd)
       {
            driver = new FirefoxDriver();
                driver.get("***********");
                driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                driver.findElement(By.id("username")).sendKeys(Usrname);
                driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys(Pwd);
                driver.findElement(By.id("login")).click();
       }

       @Test(dependsOnMethods = { "login" })
       public void logout(String Usrname, String Pwd)
       {
           driver.findElement(By.id("logout")).click();
           driver.close();
       }
```

I have used XML file as:

```
<suite name="Suite1" verbose="1" >

<test name="Factory" group-by-instances="true">
    <classes>
      <class name="test.AllMethod">
        <methods>
           <include name="login"/>
            <include name="logout"/>
        </methods>
      </class>
    </classes>
  </test>
</suite>
```

It executing like :

```
login(1)
login(2)
login(3)
logout(1)
logout(2)
logout(3)
```

How can i execute it as :

```
login(1)
logout(1)
login(2)
logout(2)
login(3)
logout(3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use `@AfterMethod` annotation for your `logout()` method, not the `@Test` one (alter your suite file accordingly).

The logout method doesn't make use of credentials passed as arguments, by the way, you can skip those.

Comment: Thanks for your replay, but its not working. Giving same result as shown above.

Comment: Well, it is working, as a matter of fact, I just tried it out. There should be something that cripples your test setup (extra annotations or extra include in the xml). Can you please paste the code and testng.xml when you use the @AfterMethod way and it doesn't work for you?

Answer (score 0):

//Dont use  @Test(dependsOnMethods = { "login" }) before logout method ,Instead use @AfterMethod

```
@Test(dataProvider = "DP")
   public void login(String Usrname, String Pwd)
   {
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            driver.get("***********");
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            driver.findElement(By.id("username")).sendKeys(Usrname);
            driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys(Pwd);
            driver.findElement(By.id("login")).click();
   }

   @AfterMethod
   public void logout(String Usrname, String Pwd)
   {
       driver.findElement(By.id("logout")).click();
       driver.close();
   }
```